# Explanation of WebGL code - why does it work that way

Tags: javascript, colors, webgl, shader, glow

I'm trying to make a lightbulb that glows a little and then it becomes less intense. Also at the edges to be a little bit dimmer. I found the a code, that I think creates the effect I want to create, but I don't seem to understand it very well. Here's the code:

```
mat2 rotate2d(float angle){
return mat2(cos(angle),-sin(angle),
            sin(angle),cos(angle));
    }

float variation(vec2 v1, vec2 v2, float strength, float speed) {
    return sin(
        dot(normalize(v1), normalize(v2)) * strength + iGlobalTime * speed
    ) / 100.0;
}

vec3 paintCircle (vec2 uv, vec2 center, float rad, float width) {

    vec2 diff = center-uv;
    float len = length(diff);

    len += variation(diff, vec2(0.0, 1.0), 5.0, 2.0);
    len -= variation(diff, vec2(1.0, 0.0), 5.0, 2.0);

    float circle = smoothstep(rad-width, rad, len) - smoothstep(rad, rad+width, len);
    return vec3(circle);
}


void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    uv.x *= 1.5;
    uv.x -= 0.25;

    vec3 color;
    float radius = 0.35;
    vec2 center = vec2(0.5);


    //paint color circle
    color = paintCircle(uv, center, radius, 0.1);

    //color with gradient
    vec2 v = rotate2d(iGlobalTime) * uv;
    color *= vec3(v.x, v.y, 0.7-v.y*v.x);

    //paint white circle
    color += paintCircle(uv, center, radius, 0.01);


    fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

I don't understand why we need the dot product of the normalized vectors and how it's chosen exacly:

```
len += variation(diff, vec2(0.0, 1.0), 5.0, 2.0);
len -= variation(diff, vec2(1.0, 0.0), 5.0, 2.0);
```

I mean - why is there first adding, then subtraction?
Then why is that:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
uv.x *= 1.5;
uv.x -= 0.25;
```

and how does this 
`vec2 v = rotate2d(iGlobalTime) * uv;
    color *= vec3(v.x, v.y, 0.7-v.y*v.x);`

make the color gradient? 
Here's a link of the code if someone prefers watching it there and what it does: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltBXRc. 
I'm obviously not very good at geometry. If someone could help me, I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we wanted to draw a perfect circle, we would simply plot all points lying a certain distance from the center of the scene. Speaking procedurally, we would start from the center, pick any random direction, go some distance `r` in that direction, and plot a point. Then return to the center, pick some other direction, go the same distance `r`, and plot another point. And so on, until we have a smooth circle:
[r = 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%3D1)

To plot a distorted circle we can vary the distance `r` depending on the direction we're facing. If we express the direction as an angle in radians (`theta`), then `r` will be some function of that angle. What function exactly? Let's try something simple first: [r = theta](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%20%3D%20theta)

Not quiet what we want, it should be more like a circle (r = 1), but with a bit of waviness (r = 1 + waviness). The simplest wavy function is [sin(x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%28x%29). Let's try to add it: [r = 1 + 0.1 * sin(5 * theta)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%20%3D%201%20%2B%200.1%20*%20sin%285%20*%20theta%29)

By changing the numbers we can manipulate the amplitude and the frequency of the waves. But there's too much symmetry, to break it we need something more complex than a sine wave.

How about this monster [sin(5 * sin(x)) - sin(5 * cos(x))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%285%20*%20sin%28x%29%29%20-%20sin%285%20*%20cos%28x%29%29)

Let's add it to the circle [r = 1 + 0.1 * sin(5 * sin(theta)) - 0.1 * sin(5 * cos(theta))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar%20plot%20r%3D%201%20%2B%200.1%20*%20sin%285%20*%20sin%28theta%29%29%20-%200.1%20*%20sin%285%20*%20cos%28theta%29%29)

Looks pretty good to me.

The shader performs exactly this distortion, but in a different manner. Taking a dot product with a standard basis vector simply gives you the X or Y coordinate of the vector. We can rewrite that bit as:

```
len += 0.02 * sin(normalize(diff).y * 5.0 + 2.0 * iGlobalTime);
len -= 0.02 * sin(normalize(diff).x * 5.0 + 2.0 * iGlobalTime);
```

X and Y coordinates of a normalized vector are just `sin` and `cos` of an angle represented by that vector. So, `normalize(diff).y` gives you the sine of an angle, and `normalize(diff).x` gives you the cosine.

Hopefully this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you :)